# Error: The abstract schema type is unknown

Tags: java, mysql, persistence

I don't understand why I get this error:

```
//EX[2,1,["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException/1755012560",
"An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
\r\nException Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM Users u]. \n[14, 19] 
The abstract schema type \x27Users\x27 is unknown."],0,7]
```

It looks like all configs are correct, but nevertheless I get this error.
Please, help. My configs are below:

**MySql table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USERNAME` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ENABLED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Entity:**

```
package com.val.dogovora.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int USER_ID;
    private String USERNAME;
    private String PASSWORD;
    private int ENABLED;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

    public Users() {
    }
    public Users(String USERNAME, String PASSWORD, int ENABLED, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        this.USERNAME = USERNAME;
        this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
        this.ENABLED = ENABLED;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }
Getters and Setters...
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<class>com.val.dogovora.entity.Users</class>
```

**code:**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DogovoraPool");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u", Users.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason of my error. Before I converted my project from Eclipse into Intellij Idea. The folder `my_project_name/war/web-if/classes` remains with old files. I deleted this folder and now my project works without any error. But I don't understand, why does Intellij Idea use these old classes, if it has it's own folder for them `my_project_name/out` ?